# Why is this regex not greedy?

Tags: regex, perl

In this regex

```
$line = 'this is a regular expression';
$line =~  s/^(\w+)\b(.*)\b(\w+)$/$3 $2 $1/;

print $line;
```

Why is $2 equal to `" is a regular "`? My thought process is that (.*) should be greedy and match all characters until the end of the line and therefore $3 would be empty.

That's not happening, though. The regex matcher is somehow stopping right before the last word boundary and populating $3 with what's after the last word boundary and the rest of the string is sent to $2.

Any explanation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$3` can't be empty when using this regex because the corresponding capturing group is `(\w+)`, which must match at least one word character or the whole match will fail.

So what happens is `(.*)` matches "`is a regular expression`", `\b` matches the end of the string, and `(\w+)` fails to match. The regex engine then backtracks to `(.*)` matching "`is a regular "` (note the match includes the space), `\b` matches the word boundary before `e`, and `(\w+)` matches "`expression`".

If you change`(\w+)` to `(\w*)` then you will end up with the result you expected, where `(.*)` consumes the whole string.

Comment: `$` is a zero-width assertion; I don't think anything consuming (if that's at all possible) the end of string would be an issue. See: http://codepad.org/CwTlhn3z

Comment: @NullUserException I thought so too but [^(\w+)\b(.*)\b(\w*)$](http://rubular.com/r/XczcfFd2Va) still matches `expression` to the last group. Making the word boundary optional results in an empty match as I expected. I'm not really sure what is going on actually...

Comment: It does look like Ruby's regex engine is different from Perl's.

Comment: After some testing starting with your Rubular link . . . it looks like Ruby is not-100%-greedy when a quantifier is followed by `\b`. Given the string `this is a regular expression`, the regex `^(\w+)\b(.*)\b` only grabs up through the space before `expression` (that is, it chooses to put the final `\b` before `expression` instead of at end-of-string), whereas the regex `^(\w+)\b(.*n)\b` grabs the whole thing (because it's willing to put `\b` at end-of-string if it has to). I really have no idea why.

Comment: I think the problem is with Rubular.  When I switch to 1.8.7 or  change the final `\b` to the equivalent lookarounds, it [works right](http://rubular.com/r/ewXzIGYihE).  It also works correctly at codepad and [ideone](http://ideone.com/SG4tR).

Comment: One additional note:  if you want the `.*` to be *really* greedy, even if it makes the match fail, use `(?>.*)` (or the equivalent possesive quantifier `.*+`)

Answer (score 6):

Greedy doesn't mean it gets to match absolutely everything. It just means it can take as much as possible **and still have the regex succeed**.

This means that since you use the `+` in group 3 it can't be empty and still succeed as `+` means **1 or more**.

If you want 3 to be empty, just change `(\w+)` to `(\w?)`. Now since `?` means 0 or 1 it can be empty, and therefore the greedy `.*` takes everything. Note: This seems to work only in Perl, due to how perl deals with lines.

Comment: http://rubular.com/r/1XFcnXANWJ, although in Perl it works as you described. Is the end of string a word boundary in Perl?

Comment: `(\w?)` means 0, or 1. `(\w*)` means 0 or more.

Comment: @BradGilbert How's that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the regex to match the whole string, `^(\w+)\b` requires that the entire first word be `\1`. Likewise, `\b(\w+)$` requires that the entire last word be `\3`. Therefore, no matter how greedy `(.*)` is, it can only capture ' is a regular ', otherwise the pattern won't match. At some point while matching the string, `.*` probably did take up the entire ' is a regular expression', but then it found that it had to backtrack and let the `\w+` get its match too.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you wrote your regexp it doesn't matter if `.*` is being greedy, or non-greedy.
It will still match.

The reason is that you used `\b` between `.*` and `\w+`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'this is a regular expression';

sub test{
  my($match,$desc) = @_;
  print '# ', $desc, "\n" if $desc;
  print "test( qr'$match' );\n";
  if( my @elem = $string =~ $match ){
    print ' 'x4,'[\'', join("']['",@elem), "']\n\n"
  }else{
    print ' 'x4,"FAIL\n\n";
  }
}

test( qr'^ (\w+) \b (.*)  \b (\w+) $'x, 'original' );
test( qr'^ (\w+) \b (.*+) \b (\w+) $'x, 'extra-greedy' );
test( qr'^ (\w+) \b (.*?) \b (\w+) $'x, 'non-greedy' );
test( qr'^ (\w+) \b (.*)  \b (\w*) $'x, '\w* instead of \w+' );
test( qr'^ (\w+) \b (.*)     (\w+) $'x, 'no \b');
test( qr'^ (\w+) \b (.*?)    (\w+) $'x, 'no \b, non-greedy .*?' );
```

```
# original
test( qr'(?^x:^ (\w+) \b (.*)  \b (\w+) $)' );
    ['this'][' is a regular ']['expression']

# extra-greedy
test( qr'(?^x:^ (\w+) \b (.*+) \b (\w+) $)' );
    FAIL

# non-greedy
test( qr'(?^x:^ (\w+) \b (.*?) \b (\w+) $)' );
    ['this'][' is a regular ']['expression']

# \w* instead of \w+
test( qr'(?^x:^ (\w+) \b (.*)  \b (\w*) $)' );
    ['this'][' is a regular expression']['']

# no \b
test( qr'(?^x:^ (\w+) \b (.*)     (\w+) $)' );
    ['this'][' is a regular expressio']['n']

# no \b, non-greedy .*?
test( qr'(?^x:^ (\w+) \b (.*?)    (\w+) $)' );
    ['this'][' is a regular ']['expression']
```